# Why am I getting a null reference exception when adding an ArrayList element to a ListBox?

Tags: c#, arraylist, listbox, compact-framework, windows-ce

This code is blowing up on the commented line with "Null Reference Exception":

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("arrLst count is {0}", arrLst.Count));
for (int i = 0; i < arrLst.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Made it into for loop"); 
    listBoxCommandsSent.Items.Add(arrLst[i]); // <-- blows up here
    MessageBox.Show("Made it past first listBoxCommandsSent.Items.Add()");
    . . .
```

arrLst is an ArrayList

The first MessageBox.Show tells me arrLst has a count of 8
The second MessageBox.Show is reached ("made it into for loop")
The third  MessageBox.Show is not reached; so, the problem is adding item 0 to the listBox.

Why is this problematic?

Note: The reasons I'm using MessageBox.Show() insted of stepping through it in a debugger are documented elsewhere on SO; in a nuts hell, I can't connect to my handheld device from within XP Mode in VS 2003.

### UPDATE

And even adding these:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("arrLst element 0 is {0}", arrLst[0].ToString()));
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("arrLst element 0 from i is {0}", arrLst[i].ToString()));
```

...show me what I'd expect (in both cases, as is to be expected):

```
arrLst element 0 is ! 0 200 200 210 1
arrLst element 0 from i is ! 0 200 200 210 1
```

I also added a "ToString" to the assignment, so that it's now:

```
listBoxCommandsSent.Items.Add(arrLst[i].ToString());
```

...but to no avail.

Comment: Is `listBoxCommandsSent` null by any chance?

Comment: Checking that `listBoxCommandsSent` is not null and that `listBoxCommandsSent.Items` is not null would be the first two to check.

Comment: Clay can you show where you are Initializing `arrLst` as well as where you are Initializing `listBoxCommandsSent`

Comment: As to your edit, the problem *couldn't* be the items you're adding.  Even if they were `null`, it wouldn't throw that exception.  `listBoxCommandsSent` is what's `null`.

Comment: I don't understand how the listbox could be null. I'm obviously missing something here.

Comment: @ClayShannon can you add a call to check if it is, just to humor us.  Or post the code where your listbox is initialized.

Comment: It IS null, but I don't grok how, nor do I know how to fix that.

Comment: Where is your listbox being initialized? you should have a call like: `ListBox listBoxCommandsSent = new ListBox()` somewhere in your code.  Can you post that?

Comment: See my reply to the answer below (it IS null, but I'm still baffled)

Comment: Where is this loop getting called in your code? Could it be that it is called before the form has fully loaded and the listbox may not be initialized yet?

Comment: @jzworkman: The Listbox is not being created dynamically...as to WHEN it's getting called, though: Ah, that's got to be it, I should have thought of that; I'm not waiting long enough for my "wine" to ferment and age before selling it (so to speak).

Comment: So I moved the code from the overloaded constructor, which solved the null reference jazz, but now the form with the ListBox displays (I think that's what I'm seeing), but it's completely devoid of controls, although at design time there is a panel, label, listbox, and button...???

Comment: Okay, adding the InitializeComponents() to my overloaded constructor solved that (pretty much; the roadblock/conundrum I've run into now is fodder for a new question (form is too large, I have to drag it around - I thought the CF automatically made forms scale to the size of the device?). jzworkman: add your comment about "called before form has fully loaded" as a question, and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you did not initialize `listBoxCommandsSent` or `listBoxCommandsSent.Items`.You can add

```
if(listBoxCommandsSent==null)
    MessageBox.Show("listBoxCommandsSent is null");
if(listBoxCommandsSent.Items==null)
    MessageBox.Show("Items is null");
```

to check what is null.

Comment: I am thinking that `listBoxCommandsSent` is null based on his description of what each MessageBox is doing / displaying

Comment: arrList[0]=null should not cause null reference exception in listBoxCommandsSent.Items.Add(arrLst[i]); line.

Comment: The `Items` property of a list box won't ever be null, and does not need to be initialized by the user of the listbox.  The listbox itself could be null though.

Comment: I don't know what is type of listBoxCommandsSent. It is not shown in his code.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov The name `listBox` is a pretty glaring clue, as well as the fact that he refers to is as a "list box" in his description of what's going on in the OP.

Comment: I am officially confused now on what the OP is wanting or trying to do.. I can't stand having to play mind  reader .. it's like pulling teeth when you ask an OP to post relevant code

Comment: listBoxCommandsSent is a ListBox, which I dragged and dropped onto the form - nothing fancy about it.

Comment: I added the checks shown above, and sure enough, I see "listBoxCommandsSent is null" which boggles my mind, because, again, it is right there on the form - how can it be null? How do I initialize the listbox control? Either my brain is already fried today, or I can't recall ever having to do something like this before...IOW, I don't have to initialize the Panel that is on the form, which got there in the same way the ListBox did (by dragging and dropping)...?